# what is the working of this command ls . | xargs -i -t cp ./{} $1

Tags: linux, bash, shell, posix, xargs

I am a new bee to bash scripting. while studying Advanced bash scripting I came across this command. I'm not understand how the command is working and what is the use of curly braces. Thanks in advance.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is better suited for unix.stackexchange.com

Comment: @UlrichSchwarz IMHO Unix and SO overlap a bit. I would say the question is not off topic for that reason. However, the fact that the OP isn't able to check `man xargs` before asking a question on SO really scares me a bit. I'm afraid that SO is not helpful sometimes. A lot of people using it to avoid investigating hard enough for themselves.

Comment: It's a complicated way of writing `cp * $1` — but it has the merit of working even if there are so many files in the current directory that `*` expands so that it is too big to fit in the argument list of the `cp` command.  Against that, it executes one copy command per file, which is expensive if there are so many files that this is necessary.

Comment: xargs does not run the command once per argument by default, but groups several arguments together.

Comment: @hop: usually, you're right.  The `-i` option changes the behaviour.

Answer (score 4):

Your command:

```
ls . | xargs -i -t cp ./{} $1
```

could be divided into the following parts:

```
  ls .
```

List the current directory (this will list all the files/directories but the hidden ones)

```
| xargs -i -t cp ./{} $1
```

Basically the xargs breaks the piped output (ls in this case) and provides each element in the list as input to the following command (cp in this case). The **-t** option is to show in the stderr what xargs is actually executing. The **-i** is used for string replacement. In this case since nothing has been provided it will substitute the **{}** by the input. $1 is the name of the destination where your files will be copied (I guess in this case it should be a directory for the command to make sense otherwise you will be copying all the files to the same destination).

So for example, if you have lets say a directory that has files called a, b, c. When you run this command it will perform the following:

```
cp ./a $1
cp ./b $1
cp ./c $1
```

**NOTE**:

The **-i** option is deprecated, **-I** (uppercase i) should be used instead